# Zend Framework 3 installation

Tags: php, xampp, zend-framework3

I installed new xampp with php 5.6.28 on my usb drive.
Then I used Composer to create a new project from scratch: `composer create-project -s dev zendframework/skeleton-application zf3`
This `zf3` folder is located on my usb `G:\xampp\zf3`

But instead `zf3 skeleton application` I got `zf2` installed.
...Installing `zendframework/skeleton-application (2.5.0)`

Then I went to Github and downloaded a compressed archive https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication. I unziped the file and put it on my usb into the directory skeleton `G:\xampp\skeleton`. I navigated to this folder `skeleton` and run 

`composer self-update
composer install`

And I got:

> "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>       - This package requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 but your PHP version (5.5.11) does not satisfy that requirement."

I have this php 5.5.11 version installed on my `C:` drive with old xampp. **What do I need to do to use my php version 5.6.28 which is on my usb?** It really confused me.

I tested a little:
When I navigate to this folder `G:\xampp\skeleton` and type `php -v` It shows me `PHP 5.5.11` but when I go to `G:\xampp\php`  and type `php -v` It shows me `PHP 5.6.28`

Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: check if the environment variable for php is setted to your c: drive, if so, than make it point to your g:

Comment: Yes, that is. Thanks a lot. I knew that's easy but I couldn't remember what i needed to do.

Comment: :) I will post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

By the comments:

Check if the environment variable for php is set to your c: drive, if so, than make it point to your g: